# Android - Google Sheets API v4 getting Error 403

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

i am trying to read google sheet's data via its `API v4`. but every time it is saying `PERMISSION_DENIED` with error code `403`

i am following it's official guide to get it done [Checkout here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android)

here are some info to set it up

```
String spreadsheetId = "1uZRU6AgOEHU4iNrLzg5NcotLeIwdhdvAxjG-tGI2zZc";
String range = "Sheet1";
```

Error response :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciable

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very happy that i resolved it by self.

just posting answer to let other know what was the problem.

actually i my google sheet was private so just made it public (accessible to all) and bingo!

Thnaks